# author's affiliation after graduation

Tags: affiliation

I would like to publish my work which is a chapter of my doctoral thesis.
One chapter has already been published with myself as a first author and my advisor as an second author.
Since I'm working in a private company as a full time employee, I wonder what should be my affiliation.

The work was completely done when I was a graduate student, but now I left the school.
I'm a full time employee now, but this work has nothing to do with my current employer.

What should be the my affiliation in my paper? The school I graduated, or my current employer?

Comment: Dual affiliation with a footnote. Make em all happy!

Comment: @BryanKrause does not answer my question.

Comment: I'm curious if is okay to write my school instead of no affiliation.

Comment: Did you read the top and accepted answer at the linked duplicate? What did it say?